# rich dataTable can not use iterate variable for a nested loop

Tags: java, jsf, arraylist, richfaces, richdatatable

I'm building a rich datatable with a dynamic amount of columns. It seems to me, that it is not a big thing, but I'm trying to get an answer since hours.
The issue is when I want to use the iteration variable from the datatable for a nested loop. In the nested loop I try to create for every row the same dynamic amount of columns.
Probably it becomes more clear when I show some code:

```
<rich:dataTable styleClass="waiDataTable" width="700"
rowClasses="odd,even" value="#{reportingModel.reportingDoiPoolRows}"
var="reportingDoiPoolRow"
rendered="#{not empty reportingModel.reportingDoiPoolRows}">

<!-- Start header of the data-table -->
<f:facet name="header">
    <rich:columnGroup>

        <rich:column rowspan="2">
            <h:outputText value="Pool" />
        </rich:column>

        <c:forEach items="#{reportingModel.headerList}" var="item">
            <rich:column colspan="2">
                <h:outputText value="#{item}" />
            </rich:column>
        </c:forEach>

        <rich:column breakRowBefore="true">
            <h:outputText value="New" />
        </rich:column>
        <rich:column>
            <h:outputText value="Tot" />
        </rich:column>

        <c:forEach begin="1" end="#{reportingModel.headerList.size()-1}">
            <rich:column>
                <h:outputText value="New" />
            </rich:column>
            <rich:column>
                <h:outputText value="Tot" />
            </rich:column>
        </c:forEach>

    </rich:columnGroup>
</f:facet>
<!-- End header of the data-table -->

<!-- Start values of the data-table -->

<rich:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{reportingDoiPoolRow.doiPool.name}"></h:outputText>
</rich:column>

<ui:repeat value="#{reportingDoiPoolRow.amountOfDois}" var="amount">
    <rich:column style="text-align:right;">
        <h:outputText value="#{amount}"/>
    </rich:column>
</ui:repeat>

<!-- Start values of the data-table -->

<f:facet name="footer">
    <rich:columnGroup>
        <rich:column style="text-align:left;">Totals</rich:column>

        <rich:column style="text-align:right;">
            <h:outputText value="12"></h:outputText>
        </rich:column>
        <rich:column style="text-align:right;">
            <h:outputText value="12"></h:outputText>
        </rich:column>

    </rich:columnGroup>
</f:facet>
```

The issue is in the following block:

```
<rich:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{reportingDoiPoolRow.doiPool.name}"></h:outputText>
</rich:column>

<ui:repeat value="#{reportingDoiPoolRow.amountOfDois}" var="amount">
    <rich:column style="text-align:right;">
        <h:outputText value="#{amount}"/>
    </rich:column>
</ui:repeat>
```

The name (`reportingDoiPoolRow.doiPool.name`) is rendered well but every column inside the `ui:repeat` is not rendered.
It seems that I can't use the reportingDoiPoolRow variable for another iteration.
The Collections which I use for the table are both from the type `ArrayList` (long).
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You should probably use `<rich:columns>` to render dymanic number of columns: http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/columns.jsf?tab=usage&cid=1222466

Comment: @MagnusTengdahl `<rich:columns>` are unfortunatelly out of Final scope. I got that here: [link](https://community.jboss.org/message/592975)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `<ui:repeat>` doesn't work because `<rich:column>` is not what ui:repeat is designed to deal with (e.g. a `<li>` or something like that), `<a4j:repeat>` which you should be using instead won't work there either (and that has something to do with the way the table is built).

`<c:forEach>` will work, with a little hack:

```
<c:forEach var="index" begin="0" end="#{reportingModel.columns - 1}">
    <rich:column style="text-align:right;">
        <h:outputText value="#{reportingDoiPoolRow.amountOfDois.get(index)}" />
    </rich:column>
</c:forEach>
```

`<c:forEach>` does not have access to the attributes from `<rich:dataTable>` (well, it has access to `rowKeyVar` but that will be always 1) so you'll have to ask the bean directly for the column size but the pieces rendered by `<c:forEach>` will have access to the `var`.

Comment: Hi @Makhiel
Thanks for your answer. You got right, it is impossible to access the attributes from the rich:dataTable inside the c:forEach. Your approche to get it with the little hack works. For my example works this hack only because I access another attribute (reportingModel.headerList) which has the same length as the reportingDoiPoolRow.amountOfDois List. If you really need this inside the c:forEach you got any alternatives? Thanks, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Won't it always have the same length? If not just save the actual length somewhere in the bean so you can access it.

Comment: OK, that is a good idea. Imagine that I have months in the header and  for every month a total value and a new value. That means two columns for one month. I solved it with that code, because I can not access the reportingDoiPoolRow.amountOfDois list:
`<c:forEach var="index" begin="0" end="#{((reportingModel.headerList.size() *2)-1)}">
 <rich:column>
  <h:outputText value="#{reportingDoiPoolRow.amountOfDois.get(index)}" />
 </rich:column>
</c:forEach>`

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate. I wasted almost a week figuring out this ridiculous behavior. Too bad they removed `<rich:columns>` in Richfaces 4.x else this hack wouldn't have been required..