# <rich:dataTable> from listOfMaps

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, ajax4jsf, richdatatable

I have a `SessionScoped` bean which has a list of maps. I am attempting to get a `<rich:dataTable>` produced using `<a4j:repeat>`.

The list of maps is being populated correctly, although there is no dataTable output. From reading articles on stack-overflow, I think my problem may be occuring due to the life-cycle problems or my novice understanding of jsf with richfaces.

*Using:* Tomcat 7, JSF 2.1x - Mojarra, Richfaces 4.x

Here is what I have so far;

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{myBean.myMap}" var="map">

    <a4j:repeat value="#{myBean.myMap[0].keySet().toArray()}" var="key">
        #{map[key]}
    </a4j:repeat>

</rich:dataTable>
```

If someone could point my in the correct direction, the help would be greatly appreciated!

***Answer:***

As stated below the solution is to instead use `<c:forEach>` and use `<rich:columns>`.

*Solution:*

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{queryBean.test}" var="map">
    <c:forEach items="#{queryBean.test[0].keySet().toArray()}" var="key">

        <rich:column style="text-align:left; width:auto;">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{key}" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{map[key]}" />
        </rich:column>

    </c:forEach>
</rich:dataTable>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic columns with richfaces 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835552/dynamic-columns-with-richfaces-4)

Comment: That was one of the posts I had read. Now that I re-read it I see no need for my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `<rich:dataTable>` has to contain columns - `<rich:column>`

Assuming you want to have dynamic table (the number of columns based on the length of the map) you will have to use `<c:forEach>` instead of `<a4j:repeat>`. I have answered a question about this a while ago, [take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394795/rich-datatable-can-not-use-iterate-variable-for-a-nested-loop/16396322#16396322).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, this correctly resolved my problem. I had looked at <c:forEach> but was hearing to avoid it.

Comment: You probably should, in general, but none of the other (`<ui:repeat>`, `<a4j:repeat>`) will work in this case.