# <rich:extendedDataTable> <c:forEach> Displaying a table via a "Map of maps"

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, jstl

I have a data model with structure : `TreeMap < String, TreeMap< String, Double>> resultMap;`
This is stored in a `SessionScoped` `ManagedBean`.

I am trying to output this via a dynamic `< rich:extendedDataTable>` where;

- Key of first map is the row label
- Value of first map is a second map ( corresponds to the columns on the row
- Key of second map is the columns header
- Value of second map is the columns value

Source Code:

```
<rich:extendedDataTable
    value="#{queryBean.resultMap.keySet().toArray()}" var="key"
    frozenColumns="1" styleClass="rich-extdt">

    <rich:column width="75px">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Mediation" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{key}" />
    </rich:column>

    <rich:column width="75px">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Test" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{queryBean.resultMap[key]}" />
    </rich:column>

    <c:forEach items="#{queryBean.resultMap[key]}" var="map">

        <rich:column width="75px">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{map.key}" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{map.value}" />
        </rich:column>

    </c:forEach>

</rich:extendedDataTable>
```

Output:

[image: Table output via source code]

The first column is correctly outputting the keys of the first map.
The second column (used for debugging) is correctly outputting the map structure ( when I apply `.keySet()` to the structure I do get all the correct keys ).

Using: jstl 1.2.0, jsf 2.1 - mojarra, richfaces 4.x, tomcat 7.

***Update:***

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394795/rich-datatable-can-not-use-iterate-variable-for-a-nested-loop/16396322#16396322), the `< c:forEach>` has no access to the `< rich:dataTable>` attributes, hence unable to use `key`. Is there any simple workaround to this?

Comment: anyone see a solution?